# Why do I still have reputation 1? (Can't vote anything up.)

Tags: support, stack-overflow, answers, specific-question

Hello! I'm trying to become an active participant on Stack Overflow. I found a question I could answer, and I answered it:

[Monitor vs Watch on SourceForge Tracker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968177/monitor-vs-watch-on-sourceforge-tracker)

Then two people voted my answer up. Per the FAQ, I thought I would get 20 reputation for this (+10 for each upvote). But my reputation still shows as "1", and therefore I can't upvote any answers myself. Is there some other bootstrap I need before my reputation will begin to climb for my answers? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. The good news is that you now have 50 rep on meta. So if you'd like to talk about unicorns, you're all set.

Comment: This is either the most endearing new user question I've seen, or the most cunning plan to get mounds of rep that has yet been conceived. +1 either way.

Comment: @Jon B: Thanks! Glad I can upvote and checkmark jjnguy's answer; he deserves it.
@Ocaasi: LOL. Nope, it was an honest question. I guess I'm endearing. :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You made your answer Community Wiki.  That means you do not earn any reputation for that answer.

There is a little checkbox that says "community wiki" that you must have checked when initially answering the question.

In the future, refrain from checking that box, and you will earn reputation from your answers/questions.

*Note:* Once any post is Community Wiki, it cannot be un-community-wiki'd.

Comment: @robert, yeah, it's a bummer.

Comment: Actually, he doesn't see the box unless he is editing the question or he has a certain rep. So he edited it and checked the box. The box is hidden for low rep users to avoid these kind of mistakes.

Comment: well, the bounty will "punch through" even on a community wiki answer. Might even be auto-awarded in this case, if the answer was provided after the bounty started.

Comment: @Jeff, the answer was provided before the bounty I believe.

Comment: you should mention that CW is not revertible...

Comment: @Tob, added, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Kop: Yes, I did have to edit the question several times; I wasn't allowed to add more than one URL IIRC (another bootstrapping issue). I must have checked the box by mistake.

Comment: @jjnguy (and all): Thanks so much for the quick and comprehensive answer. Now it makes sense. It's a real puzzler when you're brand new and trying to figure out how things work.